# Get values from page in variables

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to create a class in which I should get the detail of page in variables.
For example:

- Name:Nobody
- Email:rent.staging@gmail.com
- Phone:1209381209

i need to create a class in which i should get name in a variable and other details

```
public class GetValues {
    String name {get;set;}
    String email {get;set;}
    Integer phone {get;set;}
    public GetValues(String name, String email, Integer phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not clear what are you trying to achieve, and what kind of problems did you get

Comment: Since you have define variables with `{get;set;}`, you don't need `GetValues method`. You can fill attibute value on an html element, with `{!variable}`. Otherwise you can define a remote action, called by javascript.

Comment: {!variable} tag @DarkSkull ok let me try that, i havn't used this tag before

Comment: Obviously, you have to change "variable" with name, email or phone.

Comment: @DarkSkull can you tell me how exactly I can do it. I am a newbie in SFDC

Comment: @DarkSkull this *GetValues method* as you say is actually a constructor. I'm pretty sure you do need a constructor in a class

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>            
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section">
                <apex:inputField value="{!name}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!phone}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!email}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Because you defined variables with `get` and `set` methods, you just call variables in value attributes.

Comment: error is coming.....input field is for when you have taken some standard controller